# cancel form submit when using formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, frontend, formik

*first of all thank you so much for your time and good willing to help!*

It's the first time I am trying to manage the logic of a form using the [formik npm library](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/). It's been really easy to setup and nothing is broken.

**But I'm having a problem:** The form is being submitted anyway and its causing me troubles because it's redirecting to the `/profile` and it shouldn't.

This is my form:

```
<Formik
                initialValues={{ identifier: "sdf", password: "fgh" }}
                validate={values => {
                  let errors = {};
                  // REGEX
                  let regex = !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;

                  if (!values.identifier) {
                    errors.identifier = "El correo electrónico es requerido";
                  } else if (regex.test(values.identifier)) {
                    errors.identifier = "Invalid email address";
                  }

                  if (!values.password) {
                    errors.password = "El email es requerido";
                  }

                  return errors;
                }}
                handleSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
                  // trying to see what im receiving.
                  // I've seen this code searching around and I wanted to try
                  console.log(values, setSubmitting);
                  setTimeout(() => {
                    // submit them do the server. do whatever you like!
                    alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
                    setSubmitting(false);
                  }, 1000);
                }}
                onSubmit={values => {
                  const { identifier, password } = values;

                  this.context
                    .login({ identifier, password })
                    .then(() => {
                      window.location = "/profile";
                      this.setState({ isLoading: true, hasErrors: false });
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                      console.error(err);
                      this.setState({ isLoading: false, hasErrors: true });
                    });
                }}
                render={({
                  values,
                  errors,
                  handleSubmit,
                  handleChange,
                  handleBlur
                }) => (
                  <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} name="login">
                    <Label htmlFor="login__username">
                      {i18n.FORM.LABEL.USERNAME}
                    </Label>
                    {errors.identifier && (
                      <span color="red">{errors.identifier}</span>
                    )}
                    <Input
                      value={values.identifier}
                      type="text"
                      name="login__username"
                      placeholder={i18n.FORM.LABEL.USERNAME__PLACEHOLDER}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      required
                      data-cy="identifier"
                    />

                    <Label htmlFor="login__password">
                      {i18n.FORM.LABEL.PASSWORD}
                    </Label>
                    {errors.password && (
                      <span color="red">{errors.password}</span>
                    )}
                    <Input
                      value={values.password}
                      type="password"
                      name="login__password"
                      placeholder={i18n.FORM.LABEL.PASSWORD__PLACEHOLDER}
                      onChange={handleChange}
                      onBlur={handleBlur}
                      required
                      data-cy="password"
                    />

                    <ActionsWrapper theme={theme}>
                      <Button type="submit" size="large" fullWidth>
                        {i18n.PAGE.LOGIN.BUTTON__SUBMIT}
                      </Button>
                    </ActionsWrapper>
                  </form>
                )}
              />
```

And the function that handles the submit of the form is the one below:

```
handleOnSubmit = values => {
    const { identifier, password } = values;

    this.context
      .login({ identifier, password })
      .then(() => {
        window.location = "/profile";
        this.setState({ isLoading: true, hasErrors: false });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
        this.setState({ isLoading: false, hasErrors: true });
      });
  };
```

I've tried to search how people deals with this but, all the examples I've found did not use anything or care about the prevent of the form.

Why is that? What I'm doing wrong? Any advice? Resources?

Thank you so much for everything!

Answer (score 0):

that's not the default behavior of Forms integrated with formik.

Firstly, I think you're missing the "noValidate=true" attribute on your html form element.

Secondly, I don't think you need "handleSubmit" prop on the Formik tag. Just the onSubmit prop works.